# FileApi add file to normal form post

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, image-uploading, fileapi

I have an ASP.NET MVC application where my backend expects a list of "HttpPostedFileBase".
But now I want to add drag and drop support to upload multiple files.
I used this [guide](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-file-drag-and-drop/) to help me. In the guide they upload the images by using ajax posts. But that's not what I like to achieve here.

I want to read the files and somehow add them to my already existing form.
So when I then press my submit button the form and my images are just uploaded just as if the user would have used a filepicker (input with type file).

I already tried to add a hidden field with the base64 url in hope of mvc picking this up and translating it. But this doesn't work though. My backend knows there is something because I have one item in my list but it is null.

```js
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) {
      Output(
          "<p><strong>" + file.name + ":</strong><br />" +
          '<img src="' + e.target.result + '" /></p>'
      );

      filedropbox.append("<input type='hidden' name='Images[0]' value='" + e.target.result + "'/>");
  };

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Is this even possible? Or do I have to post the images one by one when the user just dropped them in the box. I think this is a strange way because there isn't an entity in the DB yet and the user has the ability to cancel the creation. If he does so these images will be stored on the server with no purpose because they were not connected to an entity in my DB.

One more thing:
I would like to keep the list of "HttpPostedFileBase" because of IE9 support.
When drag and drop is not supported i will use multiple inputs (type ="file).

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: MVC model binder will not recognize the hidden field as a HttpPostedFileBase, have you try setting the elemnent to `type='file'` and with `display:none` so they dont show up?

Comment: This doesn't work because most browsers will ignore this for security purposes. file inputs can only has it value set by the user. It was the first thing I tried but it is ignored on the post.

Comment: I think i have that implementation using Jquery File Upload (syncronusly) but not handy. I'll try to post it tonight! I know you are implementing from scratch but maybe you can benefit from it!